# Nested for loop using recursivity: how to access the indices of the outer loops

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, recursion, nested-loops

I was trying to make a function that is able to give the result of nested loops by using recursivity, because the number of loop can change. (and I don't want to make every nested loops manually).

For example:

```
l1=[1, 2, 3, ...., 9] #create with np.arange()
l2=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 0.9]
L=[l1,l2]
```

Then I define the **recursive loop**

```
def loop_rec(L, k):    #k is the number of parameter
    for i in L[k]:
        if (k >=0):
            loop_rec(L,k-1)
```

Imagine that I want to find the maximum value of (parameter 1 x parameter 2)

**Without recursivity**, I would have:

```
for i in L[0]:
    for j in L[1]:
        m=i*j    #m is the multiplication of the two parameters
        if m>M:
            M=m    #M is the max value
```

But with the recursive loop, I don't have "i" and "j", I only have "i".
Moreover, I don't know exactly where I should put the multiplication and the verification...

If I add **"print(i)"**:

```
def loop_rec(L, k):
    for i in L[k]:
        if (k >=0):
            loop_rec(L,k-1)
            print(i, end=';')
```

I got :

```
0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.1;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.2;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.3;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.4;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.5;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.6;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.7;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.8;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0.9;None
```

So it's seem to work, but if you can help me for the calculation and how to get each value, it would be nice of you :)

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059848/variable-number-of-predictable-for-loops-in-python?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the same, I need each value to make calculations, in the example it's only a combination of letters from the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
def loop_rec(L, k, i_in_prev_rec=None):
    if i_in_prev_rec is None:              # First call (no recursion yet)
        i_in_prev_rec = []
    if (k >=0):
        print()
        for (i, elem) in enumerate(L[k]):
            # elem contains L[k][i]
            i_in_prev_rec.append(i)        # Append i, so the next recursion can see it
            loop_rec(L,k-1, i_in_prev_rec)
            i_in_prev_rec.pop()
    else:
        print(f"Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: {i_in_prev_rec}")
        my_sum = sum([L[k][ind] for (k,ind) in enumerate(i_in_prev_rec)])
        print(f"The sum L0[ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: {my_sum}")
```

**The main call:**

```
loop_rec(L, len(L)-1)
```

**Output:**

```
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [0, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 0.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [1, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 1.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [2, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 2.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [3, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 3.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [4, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 4.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [5, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 5.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [6, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 6.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [7, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 7.8

Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 0]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.0
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 1]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.1
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 2]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.2
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 3]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.3
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 4]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.4
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 5]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.5
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 6]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.6
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 7]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.7
Reached innermost recursion/loop. The loop indices are: [8, 8]
The sum L[0][ind0] + L[1][ind1] + L[2][ind2] + ... is: 8.8
```

Comment: Thank you it work fine this way ! I just have to identify the order of apparition for each parameter and it will be good ! thanks again for your time and dedictation

Comment: @MrKanada --- You're welcome. If the answer was useful, please Upvote it. If it also addressed your posted question, please Accept the answer.